# SceneBuilder layout is not visible

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

I can not see my window using SceneBuilder in my JavaFX application.
I see the components, but my window is not there. Any ideas how I can Show my window? 
[image: This is what it Looks like]

Answer (score 0):

Ok. While writing this question, I thought it could have to do something with the size of the grid. If you set the preferredSize of the GridPane, you can see a bit more. Maybe you want to leave it with the automatic size, but I find it's a bit harder to see what you're doing like that.[image: The result]